# Not able to pass parameter to mongo find collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Req.params gets value after db.collection.find executes. Can Some one tell me what I am doing wrong with this code?

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    var postal = parseInt(req.params.postal);
    db.collection('ifscdata', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({'ADDRESS':/postal/}).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
```

Am supposed to do a partial search on address based on postal. But am not able to pass the value to postal because its getting the value only afterwards.

Function route is this

```
app.get('/ifsc/:postal', ifsc.findAll);
```

Sample URL :

> http://localhost:3000/ifsc/691009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use regex within your query, consider wrapping the variable with the [**`RegExp`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object as follows:

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    var postal = req.params.postal, 
        regex = new RegExp(postal);

    db.collection('ifscdata', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({'ADDRESS': regex}).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you :) and that was quick :P

Answer (score 0):

Why you put slashes between `postal`?

Have you tried this?

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    var postal = parseInt(req.params.postal);
    db.collection('ifscdata', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({'ADDRESS': postal}).toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
```

Comment: its like a partial comparison in mongodb. It check whether atleast part of the value is there in the field.